# Microsoft Teams Bot Adaptive card not rendering in mobile app (android)

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Microsoft Teams Bot - Adaptive card not displaying in android mobile app, it works fine in desktop app, json as below, also other card for list of records works, is that something to with empty text columns? Checked with 'adaptivecards.io' not issues reported.

**JSON added here**
https://jsfiddle.net/yaorm2en/

[image]

Comment: Which version of adaptive card are you using? Please check with 1.2. 
can you please post your actual adaptive card json here so we can try it.

Comment: Just had a quick glance now, but that json doesn't look right. It's -valid- json, but I don't think you're supposed to have two "items" like that, so it might not be valid "adaptive card" json

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Nuget 2.4.0

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow I have seen different card with same structure working

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT Json added - see link to JSFiddle on description

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. If the Action.OpenURL does not contain a valid link, the Teams mobile app will not show the whole adaptive card, but the desktop app will.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it, problem is null values in data, it does not produce json "text" property, replacing null values with empty string works